# How to skip initializing the 1st returned value from a function? - Python

Tags: python, function, initialization, return

Often i only need the 2nd `thing` that was returned from a function; for example the code below where i want get a list of `.txt` files and get the filenames without the extension:

```
import os, glob
indir = "/home/alvas/whatever/"
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(indir,'*'):
  PATH, FILENAME = os.path.split(infile)
  FILENAME.rstrip(".txt")
```

Instead of doing:

```
PATH, FILENAME = os.path.split(infile)
```

I could also do:

```
FILENAME = os.path.split(infile)[1]
```

**Are there other ways of doing this?**

Comment: `_, FILENAME = os.path.split(infile)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idiomatic way is to do

```
_, FILENAME = os.path.split(infile)
```

With the convention that `_` is a variable that you are discarding or ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
_, filename = os.path.split(infile)
```